# How to properly append to a JTextPane

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, append, jtextpane

I have a JTextPane which is called outputField, and when the user presses a button called 'list' it will run a function to search through an ArrayList with loops, and display the contents. The issue is I am currently appending each like this:

```
output = output + " " + passengers.get(x).get(y);
```

The issue with this is that if I continue to press the 'list' button, it will continue to append the same values over and over again, instead of resetting each time the user presses the 'list' button. I've tried setting

```
String output = "";
```

at the start of the function however, it did not work. Here is the whole function:

```
private void listButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    String output = "";
    passengers.add(firstName);
    passengers.add(lastName);
    passengers.add(weekOne);
    passengers.add(weekTwo);
    passengers.add(weekThree);
    passengers.add(weekFour);
    for (int y=0; y<numOfPas; y++) {
          for (int x=0; x<passengers.size(); x++) {
               output = output + " " + passengers.get(x).get(y);
           }
           output = output + "\n";
    }
    outputField.setText(output);
}
```

If I have these values in the array, this is the output of 'list'

values

> John Doe 100 200 300 400
>   
> Jerry Glock 200 400 600 800

output:
Run 'list' once:

> John Doe 100 200 300 400
>   
> Jerry Glock 200 400 600 800

Run 'list' twice:

> John Doe 100 200 300 400 John Doe 100 200 300 400
>   
> Jerry Glock 200 400 600 800 Jerry Glock 200 400 600 800
>   
> etc.

Would like for it to be the Run 'list' once results every time it is run

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer to my own question! The issue was that I was appending each individual arraylist, to the main arraylist inside the method. I simply changed this:

```
private void listButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    String output = "";
    passengers.add(firstName);
    passengers.add(lastName);
    passengers.add(weekOne);
    passengers.add(weekTwo);
    passengers.add(weekThree);
    passengers.add(weekFour);
    for (int y=0; y<numOfPas; y++) {
          for (int x=0; x<passengers.size(); x++) {
               output = output + " " + passengers.get(x).get(y);
           }
           output = output + "\n";
    }
    outputField.setText(output);
}
```

To this:

```
private void listButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    String output = "";
    for (int y=0; y<numOfPas; y++) {
          for (int x=0; x<passengers.size(); x++) {
               output = output + " " + passengers.get(x).get(y);
           }
           output = output + "\n";
    }
    outputField.setText(output);
}

private void formWindowOpened {
    passengers.add(firstName);
    passengers.add(lastName);
    passengers.add(weekOne);
    passengers.add(weekTwo);
    passengers.add(weekThree);
    passengers.add(weekFour);
}
```

and it is working flawlessly now.

Comment: *"I have found the answer to my own question!"* Then please accept the answer to make it easier to find. Same advice for your earlier questions, of which only one has an accepted answer.